# How to specify the Actor to process messages from a specific port

Tags: java, akka

Right now i try to use Akka in quite a simple, as it seems, use case. I want a specific `Actor` to handle messages that i get over TCP, but i can't achieve that and the documentation does not seem clear enough. Here is what i have now:

**Application.conf:**

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
 }
}
```

**Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("Server");
        ActorRef a = system.actorOf(Props.create(SampleActor.class), "Messages");
        a.tell("testmessage", a);
    }
}
```

**SampleActor**

```
public class SampleActor extends UntypedActor {

    private final LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) {
        log.info("Sample actor: " + msg.toString());
    }
}
```

But i don't know hot to get `SampleActor` to process messages that i receive at 127.0.0.1:2552.
This is the output i get when i run this app and visit 127.0.0.1:2552 in browser exactly once:

```
[INFO] [07/22/2014 15:39:50.953] [main] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [07/22/2014 15:39:51.086] [main] [Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://Server@127.0.0.1:2552]
[INFO] [07/22/2014 15:39:51.087] [main] [Remoting] Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://Server@127.0.0.1:2552]
[INFO] [07/22/2014 15:39:51.092] [Server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://Server/user/Messages] Sample actor: testmessage
[INFO] [07/22/2014 15:39:59.796] [Server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6993-2] Message [akka.remote.transport.AssociationHandle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://Server/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6993-2#455049767] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [07/22/2014 15:39:59.797] [Server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6994-1] Message [akka.remote.transport.AssociationHandle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://Server/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6994-1#548527175] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [07/22/2014 15:39:59.800] [Server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6995-3] Message [akka.remote.transport.AssociationHandle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://Server/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6995-3#-105273249] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [07/22/2014 15:39:59.933] [Server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6996-4] Message [akka.remote.transport.AssociationHandle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://Server/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6996-4#2016773005] was not delivered. [4] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [07/22/2014 15:39:59.934] [Server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6997-5] Message [akka.remote.transport.AssociationHandle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://Server/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6997-5#-1053639148] was not delivered. [5] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [07/22/2014 15:39:59.936] [Server-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6998-6] Message [akka.remote.transport.AssociationHandle$Disassociated] from Actor[akka://Server/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://Server/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3A%2F%2FServer%40127.0.0.1%3A6998-6#-1709546418] was not delivered. [6] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I am absolutely new to Akka so i think i'm missing something very simple. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For remoting you need to run 2 separate actor systems, the server with the config you specified above and the client with the following config

This will tell Akka that the sample actor is instantiated at the remote system and will route messages send accordingly

```
akka {
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    deployment {
      /Messages {
        remote = "akka.tcp://Server@127.0.0.1:2553"
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood the whole remoting mechanism of Akka in a very wrong way, but now managed to make it work the way i really wanted to (your comment helped me to understand what i wanted).

Comment: You might be also interested in Akka IO (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/io.html) which is useful for general-purpose client-server setups using TCP or UDP. Akka Remoting is designed for P2P communication between ActorSystems but not for integration with external systems.